# BFMatcher match in OpenCV assertion failed when using a webcam

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to use ORB feature matching, to match an image with my webcam's video.
But when I run the code I get an error:

```
    matches = bf.match(des1, des2)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\sr
c\batch_distance.cpp:275: error: (-215:Assertion failed) type == src2.type() &&
src1.cols == src2.cols && (type == CV_32F || type == CV_8U) in function 'cv::bat
chDistance'
```

When I try to use some sample video from my hard drive instead of webcam's video everything works just fine.
My webcam is working and if I try to show an image from it using opencv it works great.

Here is the full code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
      
img = cv2.imread("ketchup.jpg",0)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
orb = cv2.ORB_create()

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)        
    
    kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img, None)
    kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(frame, None)
    
    bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck = True)
    
    matches = bf.match(des1, des2)
    matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)
    
    res = cv2.drawMatches(img, kp1, frame, kp2, matches[:10], None, flags=2)
    
    cv2.imshow('frame', res)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Additional information:
I'm using Python 3.7.9
OS: Windows 7
webcam: SCB-0355N
I use cv2.CAP_DSHOW, because without it opencv throws an error that some codec is not supported

Comment: You can't mix with imread cv2.VideoCapture. Both will be imread.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Could you give the code example? I don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: @OlegRiabov The error message shows you few possible reasons for failure (in C++ syntax). It is most likely that `src1.cols == src2.cols` is `false`. That means that the two images have different width. Try resizing `frame` after `cv2.cvtColor`, example: `frame = cv2.resize(frame, img.shape[::-1])`. (You don't have to use the exact syntax with `[::-1]`, just make sure the `img` and `frame` have the same number of columns).

Comment: `assert img is not None`, `assert cap.isOpened()`, `if not ret: break` -- insert those in the correct places